# Unable to figure out MIPS error in MARS: Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000 Go: execution terminated with errors

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to translate this simple C fragment into MIPS:

```
int leaf_example(int g, int h, int i, int j) {
    int f;
    f = (g + h) - (i + j);
    return f;
}
```

This is my MIPS code:

```
.text
    main:
        leaf:
            addi $sp, $sp, -8   #adjust stack to make room for 3 items
            sw $t1, 8($sp)      #save register $t1 for use in memory location 8
            sw $t0, 4($sp)      #save register $t0 for use in memory location 4
            sw $s0, 0($sp)      #save register $s0 for use in memory location 0

            add $t0, $a0, $a1   #register $t0 contains $a0 + $a1
            add $t1, $a2, $a3   #register $t1 contains $a2 + $a3
            sub $s0, $t0, $t1   #$t0 = $t0 - $t1 -> $t0 = ($a0 + $a1) - ($a2 + $a3)

            add $v0, $s0, $zero #copy $s0 to return register $v0

            #Before returning, we restore three original values of registers we pushed onto stack by popping them
            lw $s0, 0($sp)      #restore register $s0 for caller
            lw $t0, 4($sp)      #restore register $t0 for caller
            lw $t1, 8($sp)      #restore register $t1 for caller
            addi $sp, $sp, 8    #adjust stack to delete 3 items

            jr $ra          #jump back to calling routine
```

However, when I compile and attempt to run this, it gives me this error:

"Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors."

I do not understand this error at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You store 12 bytes on the stack but only allocated space for 8.

Comment: `PC` points to next instruction in memory to be executed. If it points to `0x0000` then your `PC` is pointing somewhere wrong. You might have override it somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Jester What do you mean? It starts at 0, and I have three items 0, 4, and 8.

Should my code be `addi $sp, $sp, -12 ... ` instead?

Comment: Yes, `-12`. You put 12 bytes on the stack, you need to allocate 12 bytes. As it is, you only own `0($sp)` through `7($sp)`, you don't own `8($sp)` through `11($sp)` where the caller probably has important information that you overwrite ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to save and restore `$t0,$t1`  Since if the calling function does not use those registers, the
effort to save and restore them is wasted. To avoid this waste, MIPS divides
registers into preserved and nonpreserved categories. The preserved registers include `$s0 – $s7` (hence their name, saved). The nonpreserved registers
include `$t0 – $t9` (hence their name, temporary). A function must save and
restore any of the preserved registers that it wishes to use, but it can change
the nonpreserved registers freely.

```
.text
main:

        addi $a0,$0,1       #argument 0 = 1
        addi $a1,$0,2       #argument 1 = 2
        addi $a2,$0,3       #argument 2 = 3
        addi $a3,$0,4       #argument 3 = 4
        jal  leaf           # call function leaf
        add  $s0,$v0,$zero  # return value

        li $v0,10
        syscall


    leaf:
        addi $sp, $sp, -12  #adjust stack to make room for 3 items
        sw $s0, 8($sp)      #save register $t1 for use in memory location 8
        sw $t0, 4($sp)      #save register $t0 for use in memory location 4
        sw $t1, 0($sp)      #save register $s0 for use in memory location 0

        add $t0, $a0, $a1   #register $t0 contains $a0 + $a1
        add $t1, $a2, $a3   #register $t1 contains $a2 + $a3
        sub $s0, $t0, $t1   #$t0 = $t0 - $t1 -> $t0 = ($a0 + $a1) - ($a2 + $a3)

        add $v0, $s0, $zero #copy $s0 to return register $v0

        #Before returning, we restore three original values of registers we pushed onto stack by popping them
        lw $t1, 0($sp)      #restore register $s0 for caller
        lw $t0, 4($sp)      #restore register $t0 for caller
        lw $s0, 8($sp)      #restore register $t1 for caller
        addi $sp, $sp, 12    #adjust stack to delete 3 items

        jr $ra         #jump back to calling routine
```

The improved version.

```
 .text
 main:

        addi $a0,$0,2       #argument 0 = 2
        addi $a1,$0,3       #argument 1 = 3
        addi $a2,$0,4       #argument 2 = 4
        addi $a3,$0,5       #argument 3 = 5
        jal  leaf           # call function leaf
        add  $s0,$v0,$zero  # return value

        li $v0,10
        syscall


    leaf:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4   #adjust stack to make room for 3 items
        sw $s0, 0($sp)      #save register $t1 for use in memory location 8


        add $t0, $a0, $a1   #register $t0 contains $a0 + $a1
        add $t1, $a2, $a3   #register $t1 contains $a2 + $a3
        sub $s0, $t0, $t1   #$t0 = $t0 - $t1 -> $t0 = ($a0 + $a1) - ($a2 + $a3)

        add $v0, $s0, $0    #copy $s0 to return register $v0

                            #Before returning, we restore three
                            #original values of registers we pushed
                            #onto stack by popping them

        lw $s0, 0($sp)      #restore register $t1 for caller
        addi $sp, $sp, 4    #adjust stack to delete 3 items

        jr $ra              #jump back to calling routine
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MARS initialized the register `$ra` to `0x00000000` and using `jr $ra`, the program jumped to `0x00000000`, which is considered as invalid.

I guess you should write some code that calls the function `leaf` (and then exit via [system call](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) no. 10) after `main:` to test your function.

Comment: Ok...how would I do this?